# Octokit PUT request to replace topics from GitHub actions is throwing 403

Tags: javascript, node.js, github-actions, github-api, cicd

I am trying to update the GitHub repo topics from GitHub workflow. I am using node.js file and Ocktokit as follows

github-action

```
  - name: touchup
    env:
      TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      OWNER: ${{ github.event.repository.owner.login }}
      REPO: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}
    run: node touchup.js
```

```js
// touchup.js
if (process.env.TOKEN) {
    const { Octokit } = require("octokit");
    // Octokit.js
    // https://github.com/octokit/core.js#readme
    const octokit = new Octokit({
        auth: process.env.TOKEN,
    });

    const octoOptions = {
        owner: process.env.OWNER,
        repo: process.env.REPO,
        headers: {
            "X-GitHub-Api-Version": "2022-11-28",
        },
    };
    octokit.request("GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/topics", octoOptions).then(({ data }) => {
        octoOptions.names = [...new Set([...data.names, ...packageJson.keywords])];
        if (octoOptions.names.length != data.names.length)
            octokit
                .request("PUT /repos/{owner}/{repo}/topics", octoOptions)
                .then(console.log)
                .catch(console.error);
    });
}
```

I can see that the get request is working, but the post request is throwing 403 error. Here is GitHub documentation recommending this approach - https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#authentication-example-for-github-actions